# Function to find remainder of a^b where a, b are positive integers

Tags: java, algorithm

I was solving the problem using below code but I am getting a NullPointerException in the below line
    pw.println(fastMod(a,b,BigInteger.TEN));

I am getting NullPointerException while returning a BigInteger value.
Please suggest and help me out. Thanks.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class ModularExponential {
    static StringTokenizer st; 
    static BufferedReader br;
    static PrintWriter pw;

private static BigInteger fastMod(BigInteger base, BigInteger exponent,BigInteger modulo) {

    BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
    while (BigInteger.ZERO.compareTo(exponent) > 0) {
        if (exponent.testBit(0)) 
            result = (result.multiply(base)).mod(modulo);
        exponent = exponent.shiftRight(1);
        base = (base.multiply(base)).mod(modulo);
    }
    return result.mod(modulo);
}

public static String next() throws IOException{
    while(! st.hasMoreTokens())
        st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
    return st.nextToken();
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    st = new StringTokenizer("");
    BigInteger a,b;
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int T = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    while(T-- > 0) {
        a = new BigInteger(next());
        b = new BigInteger(next());
        pw.println(fastMod(a,b,BigInteger.TEN));
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Something like `pw = new PrintWriter( .... );` is missing. Change `pw` into `System.out` for testing.

Comment: By the way I think the built in modPow function does the same as your fastMod function.

Answer (score 4):

Your `PrintWriter pw` is `null`. You did not initialize it anywhere.

e.g. `pw = new PrintWriter( System.out );`

to print out the content on the standard out.